# Rails - God - LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, resque, permission-denied, god

I've installed god to use to monitor and start/stop/restart my resque tasks. The problem I'm getting is that I can't load the god config files.

It gives me this error:

```
$god load config/resque.god
The server is not available (or you do not have permissions to access it)
```

Then I try with

```
$sudo god load config/resque.god
.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4] (Gem::LoadError)...
```

What am I missing here? Do I need to give the god gem some kind of permission? I'm on OSX.

Comment: Is god already running? `ps aux | grep god`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
rvmsudo god load config/resque.god
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to dynamically load resque into a already running god instance?

If not, you can load the config file by using **-c**

Try running

`$god -c config/resque.god`

The **load** command will try to dynamically load the config file into a god that is already running. It's telling you that god is not running, so you can't dynamically load a config file into it.

See [dynamically loading config files into an already running god](http://godrb.com/#wiki-_dynamically_loading_config_files_into_an_already_running_god) for more information on the load command.

You can check which workers are running using

```
god status
```

If god isn't running it'll give you the same server is not available message.